# Unwrapping with flatMap

Tags: swift, calendar, swift4, option-type, nsdatecomponents

I want to get the weekday int of a date that I know exists like this:

```
let dayOfWeek =  Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: row.date).weekday
```

However, this returns an optional, and I'm trying to figure out how to avoid force unwrapping it.

My though was to do:

```
let dayOfWeek = (row.date).compactMap( { Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: $0).weekday!
})
```

However this gives me the error "value of type 'Date' has no member 'compactMap'"

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or how I should go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No optionals are needed. It's simply:

```
let dayOfWeek = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: row.date)
```

---

Note, `flatMap` is not relevant here because `row.date` is not an optional. But even if it were, it's worth noting that the `Optional` method `flatMap` has not had its name changed. It's still `flatMap`. Only the `Sequence` method of this name has been changed to `compactMap`.

See [Swift Evolution 0187: Introduce `Sequence.compactMap(_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/8d9f51f060b8c772f7adabee486112a97569d2b3/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md)

---

So, this is still `flatMap`:

```
let foo: Int? = 42
let bar: String? = foo.flatMap { i -> String in
    return "The value is \(i)"
}
// Optional("The value is 42")
```

Note, the returned value is an optional `String?`. In your example, it looks like you're trying to use `flatMap` to unwrap your optional, but that's not what `flatMap` is for. It's for calling the closure if it can unwrap `foo`, but for returning `nil` if it can't unwrap it. So it just returns another optional (a `String?` in my above example).

The `flatMap` that has been renamed to `compactMap` in Swift 4.1 is the `Sequence` rendition:

```
let baz = ["1", "2", "x", "3"]

let qux: [Int] = baz.compactMap { string -> Int? in
    return Int(string) // return integer value if it could convert it, return `nil` if not
}
// [1, 2, 3]
```

To make it even more confusing, there is still `flatMap` used with sequences:

```
let letters = ["a", "b", "c"]

let quux = letters.map { Array(repeating: $0, count: 3) }
// [["a", "a", "a"], ["b", "b", "b"], ["c", "c", "c"]]

let quuz = letters.flatMap { Array(repeating: $0, count: 3) }
// ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If I were to use flatMap in this case, how come I still do get the error "Value of type 'Date' has no member 'flatMap'"?

Comment: This `flatMap` is a method of the type called `Optional`. But `row.date` is clearly not an optional. So it doesn't make sense to use it in that context. Frankly, the use of `flatMap` method of `Optional` is often better accomplished through the use of optional chaining, anyway. But, here's an example if you were going to use it: `let foo: Int? = 42; let bar = foo.flatMap { "The value is \($0)" } ?? "There is no value"`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to avoid forced unwrapping in this case. While `weekday` is optional, it will never be `nil` when you specifically request the `.weekday` component.

```
let dayOfWeek = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: row.date).weekday!
```